# Did the Ring give Sauron any powers apart from controlling the other rings of power?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-one-ring, sauron

Sauron was defeated multiple times while he was in possession of the Ring. What does the Ring actually allow Sauron to do that he could not do without it? Did it make him more powerful in battle? Did it give him control over vast armies. What power, apart from controlling other rings of power (or those who wore them) did it give him?

Comment: @WadCheber That does not answer the question. My question is specifically regarding what the One Ring allowed Sauron to do that he could not do without it, apart from controlling the other Rings.

Comment: @ulmo Do [What is the point of Sauron making the One Ring?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35448/what-is-the-point-of-sauron-making-the-one-ring) and [Would the One Ring even work for anyone but Sauron?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48180/would-the-one-ring-even-work-for-anyone-but-sauron) (read the answers) together solve your question?

Comment: That one answers it.

Comment: "But to [make the Ring, Sauron] had been obliged to let a great part of his own inherent power (a frequent and very significant motive in myth and fairy-story) pass into the One Ring. **While he wore it, his power on earth was actually enhanced.** But even if he did not wear it, that power existed and was in 'rapport' with himself: he was not 'diminished'. "